# login twitter using twitter4j api without opening user authentication page in android

Tags: android, twitter4j

i am using twitter4j api for logging on the twiter and post tweets.
i have also registered the app on https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and got consumer key and secret.

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
Configuration configuration = builder.build();

TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
twitter = factory.getInstance();
requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
String url = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();

browser  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1_test);
browser.loadUrl(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

this is the code i m using to login. but the problem is that this opens a user authentication form in webview that takes username and password . i want to avoid opening that webpage and give login in password programatically. please help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found this tutorial really helpful, please check this:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
        Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");
        new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this, consumer, provider, prefs).execute(uri);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for the help but the problem is the same i dont want to open authntication page in my app . i want to give username and password in my code.

Comment: no way to do this. that's not allowed to make user write down their own passwords

Comment: @MSaudi the Instagram app lets you type your Twitter username and password without sending you to a webview/browser

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Twitter offers an API for user authentication; only a user authentication webpage. You can check out their API documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs